# Duplicate reference to mscorlib CS1703 Error

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

So I am currently working on migrating an application that was living on a windows 2k3 server to a machine running Windows 2012 server. After moving the site over, setting the app pool correctly and configuring the rest of the site, I am receiving this error. After doing some research it appears to be a reference to one of the main .net core libraries, and they are added by default to any project started in Visual Studio. I have not been able to find them referenced within the project anywhere. I've pretty much exhausted google search and have not been able to find a solution to this problem.

The error:

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource
>   required to service this request. Please review the following specific
>   error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1703: An assembly with the same identity
>   'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been imported. Try
>   removing one of the duplicate references.
>
> Source Error:
>
> [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File:    Line: 0
>
> Show Detailed Compiler Output:
>
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv> "C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQ
>   Preview\Bin\csc.exe" /noconfig /fullpaths
>   @"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET
>   Files\cts\67846b7a\f5d88660\sfsllqyb.cmdline"
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# 2005 Compiler version 8.00.50916 for Microsoft
>   (R) Windows (R) 2005 Framework version 2.0.50727 Copyright (C)
>   Microsoft Corporation 2001-2005. All rights reserved.
>
> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscorlib.dll: error
>   CS1703: An assembly with the same identity 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' has already been
>   imported. Try removing one of the duplicate references.
>   c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll: (Location
>   of symbol related to previous error)
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.6.1069.1

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: looks like you have two different versions of .Net framework used by the application . I am saying this because the paths are pointing out the framework version (v4.0.30319  and v2.0.50727). I recommend you start by verifying if it is actually needed to use two different versions of .Net and take it from there

Comment: Thanks. I'm kind of struggling to figure out how the application is utilizing two different versions of .NET. Is this being determined by say the app pool using .NET 4.0 CLR and the project utilizing the 2.0 framework? Whenever I try to set the app pool to 2.0 I get errors dealing with an assembly being built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime. The app originally ran on the 2.0 framework on the old server. This is just confusing all around for me atm.

Comment: Depending on the number of projects and the 3rd party components that you are using, this can be a time consuming task. In Visual Studio, each project's framework version can be defined/updated if you right click on the project name (in Solution Explorer) and going to the 'Properties'. You can view and set the 'Target Framework' and rebuild after all are set. If you are using 3rd party libraries and controls, then you probably have to stick with the same .net version that your 3rd party is using.

Comment: Basically, each assembly can use one and only one version of .Net and at least one of your assemblies is referring to two versions. After you are confident that all your assemblies are built using the proper .Net version, then you want to review your deployed assemblies to make sure you are not accidentally deploying any wrong version.  and the next step would be checking the App pool properties

Comment: Awesome. Okay thank you. Have now run into a whole host of new errors, but this is a step in the right direction! Thank you so much.